# Does antimatter have a quantum field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, antimatter

I have a theory that all quantum objects have a quantum field but does anti-matter have a quantum field if it does not then does that mean it can only react through axions

Comment: Why wouldn't it? And why is this tagged solid-state-physics?

Comment: Remember that antimatter was *predicted* from the Dirac equation, which describes quantum fields.

Comment: Quantum fields and quantum theory were predicted by einstein but paul dirac did help and solid-state physics has to do with matter and how matter works

Comment: also it might not because anti-matter cannot undergo chemical reactions like "normal" matter

Comment: Anti-hydrogen seems to work just fine, so chemical reactions seem to be covered...

Comment: Why do you say that antimatter cannot undergo chemical reactions? In an antimatter environment chemistry would be the same.

Comment: but thats where you're wrong anti-matter like strange matter turns chemistry upside down

Comment: The only thing that changes in chemistry for antimatter is the sign of the charges....but if you just take normal chemistry and redefine the proton to have a negative charge it would literally be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, antimatter is described by quantum fields, just like regular matter. For example, a single field with four components describes both electrons and positrons. (There are four components because electrons and positrons each have two spin states.)